# Show Slider Unless Upsells Exist - PHP if Statment

Tags: php, magento

I am using this code below:

```
<div class="feat-product">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('feat_products')->toHtml() ; ?>
</div>
<div id="products-recently-viewed" style="border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc; padding-bottom:10px;">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
</div>
```

At the moment you can see both blocks are being shown, I want to make it so only the feat_products always shows `UNLESS` there are products in the Upsell of the product which in that case I need it to not show the feat_products and `ONLY` show the upsell section.

Hope someone has stumbled across this before and can help out.

Comment: What is the value of `$this->getChildHtml('upsell_products')` if there are **no** upsell_products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, you can embed conditionals and put html in the middle. For instance:

```
<?php if (strlen($this->getChildHtml('upsell_products')) > 0) { ?>
<div class="feat-product">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('feat_products')->toHtml() ; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I am presuming that your getChildHtml function returns an empty string if there are no products. Tweak as needed...

Comment: While purely a matter of style, I find that PHP's alternate control structure syntax is much easier to read when mixing PHP and HTML - endif is much easier to find while scanning code, especially when the previous developers left messy, un-tabbed code for you to look at.